# ECSlidingController 2 right menu icons missing

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have created my App with the awesome ECSildingViewController 2.0. but when i just found the UITableViewCell on the right menu cannot display the icons. it works great on the left menu. Please find the screenshot here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Og5Nb.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxCI2.jpg

```
- (NSArray *)menuItems {
    if (_menuItems) return _menuItems;

    _menuItems = @[@"Item 1",@"Item 2"];
    _menuIcons = @[@"play.png",@"heart.png"];

    return _menuItems;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.menuItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSString *menuItem = self.menuItems[indexPath.row];
    NSString *menuIcon = self.menuIcons[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = menuItem;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:menuIcon];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It looks like an alignment issue.  Notice in your second image how part of the search bar is beneath the center view.  Try adjusting anchorLeftPeekAmount and anchorLeftRevealAmount.

Comment: Thx a lot Neal. I found the anchorLeftPeekAmount and anchorLeftRevealAmount are fine.
So i reduce the width of the UITableView from 320 to 276 (anchorLeftPeekAmount default is 44). then it display correctly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx a lot Neal. I found the anchorLeftPeekAmount and anchorLeftRevealAmount are fine. So i reduce the width of the UITableView from 320 to 276 (anchorLeftPeekAmount default is 44). then it display correctly !